# asymptotic equivalence

Tags: asymptotics

i have a question about asymptotic equivalence which means

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$ with notation $f(n) \sim g(n)$.

I know that the following holds:

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_{jnk}(h) \sim \int_{0}^{\infty}a_{nk}(x,h)dx \hspace{0,1cm} \forall $ fixed $ n,k \in \mathbb{N} $ and for $ h \to \infty $

My question is now if the following implication holds or under which conditions it holds?

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{jnk}(h) b_{nk} \sim \int _{0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{nk}(x,h) b_{nk} dx$ for $ h \to \infty$

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do your symbols mean? In particular $b_{nk}$ and the ordered pair.

Comment: $b_{nk}$ is a real valued sequence with indices $n$ and $k$.

$a_{jnk}(x,h)$ does only mean that it is a real valued sequence which depends on the indices $j,n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ and the real numbers $x,h$.